# Localization not found after changing Topology Configuration

Tags: web8.5, topology-manager

Adding a new **Ttm-Website** in our cd environment has made this environment not available anymore. We have added a new website domain, restarted the preview service and when we launch a request, it's a 404 ERROR, saying that Localization is not found. We have also executed:

**Sync-TtmCdEnvironment**

but still not working. We decided to republish the page and the publish settings, but still getting the same error. Any ideas? We are using DXA 2.0

[image]

In the session service log we get the following:

```
2018-09-17 13:27:15,282 ERROR ODataFunctionProcessorImpl - Unexpected exception when executing a function.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Not possible to retrieve the dynamic configuration
        at com.tridion.dynamiccontent.DynamicContent.getInstance(DynamicContent.java:81)
        at com.sdl.web.content.datalayer.dynamic.DynamicContentProvider.getPublicationMappingFromUrl(DynamicContentProvider.java:38)
        at com.sdl.web.content.odata.function.dynamic.GetPublicationMappingsFunction.doContentServiceOperation(GetPublicationMappingsFunction.java:42)
        at com.sdl.web.content.odata.function.dynamic.GetPublicationMappingsFunction.doContentServiceOperation(GetPublicationMappingsFunction.java:20)
        at com.sdl.web.content.odata.ContentServiceOperation.doOperation(ContentServiceOperation.java:36)
        at com.sdl.odata.processor.ODataFunctionProcessorImpl.doFunction(ODataFunctionProcessorImpl.java:64)
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:37)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
        at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataQueryProcessorActor.aroundReceive(ODataQueryProcessorActor.scala:29)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

After reading some posts, we executed also the **discovery-registration update** and we've got this error.
[image]

UPDATE

[image]

This is the TtmMapping

```
    [{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-47-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/ar",
    "Id": "Mapping4",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-46-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/fr",
    "Id": "Mapping3",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-5-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestLive_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/en",
    "Id": "Mapping30",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-52-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/pt",
    "Id": "Mapping8",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-5-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/en",
    "Id": "Mapping1",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-51-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/se",
    "Id": "Mapping7",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-62-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/hr",
    "Id": "Mapping16",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-63-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/ee",
    "Id": "Mapping17",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-60-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/th",
    "Id": "Mapping14",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-61-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/sp",
    "Id": "Mapping15",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-58-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/jp",
    "Id": "Mapping12",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-59-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/kr",
    "Id": "Mapping13",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-55-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/it",
    "Id": "Mapping10",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-56-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/cn",
    "Id": "Mapping11",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-64-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/lt",
    "Id": "Mapping18",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-65-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/gr",
    "Id": "Mapping19",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-49-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/no",
    "Id": "Mapping5",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-45-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/es",
    "Id": "Mapping2",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-72-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/hu",
    "Id": "Mapping26",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-73-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/is",
    "Id": "Mapping27",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-70-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/sl",
    "Id": "Mapping24",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-71-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/uk",
    "Id": "Mapping25",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-68-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/cz",
    "Id": "Mapping22",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-69-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/sk",
    "Id": "Mapping23",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-66-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/id",
    "Id": "Mapping20",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-67-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/bg",
    "Id": "Mapping21",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-48-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/de",
    "Id": "Mapping28",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-54-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/pl",
    "Id": "Mapping29",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-50-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/nl",
    "Id": "Mapping6",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-53-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestStaging_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/ru",
    "Id": "Mapping9",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
},
{
    "$type": "Tridion.TopologyManager.Data.MappingData, Tridion.TopologyManager.Data",
    "CmEnvironmentId": "TridioncmDev",
    "PublicationId": "tcm:0-45-1",
    "WebApplicationId": "TestLive_RootWebApp",
    "RelativeUrl": "/es",
    "Id": "Mapping31",
    "ExtensionProperties": []
}]
```

We have restarted our web application, but it's not working

Comment: Please provide the output of Get-TtmWebsite and Get-TtmMapping?, Maybe PublicationMapping cached. Refresh the cache and reload the settings in the Web app by In IIS, recycle your website Application Pool or by accessing http://localhost:8080/admin/refresh?allSiteLocalizations=true

Comment: In your question you say you restarted the "preview service". Did you also restart the content service and discovery service ? Does restarting these services change anything?

Comment: We restarted all the CIS services, but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a hotfix available for this, Please raise it to SDL support.

Answer (score 1):

This issue and resolution are described in the following SDL Knowlegde Base article:

https://gateway.sdl.com/CommunityKnowledge?articleName=000005260.